# Why does the author write "GE division" instead of "GE's division"?

Tags: possessives

For the sentence below, I don't understand why the author doesn't use the possessive form - he writes "GE division" instead of "GE's division" - GE standing for the company General Electric:

"To boost them further, Mr Welch slashed costs and sold flagging units, insisting that every *GE division* be first or second in its industry."

I am all the more surprised that the author uses it everywhere else in the article:

•   Mr Welch revved up *GE's* propellers

•   To tame *GE's* bloated bureaucracy...

•   *GE’s* industrial and power divisions eked out barely a tenth each

•   ... troubles at *GE’s* core industrial units.

•   etc.

Best regards

Comment: You'd have to say "... every one of GE's divisions ..."

Comment: I am not really sure to understand why it is incorrect to say "every GE's division"?

Comment: AFAIK, 'every' is a kind of  determiner. So it goes with a noun or pronoun, and General Electric (GE) forms a noun modifier on the noun. If you want to use the possessive, it would be: "every one of General Electric's divisions...

Comment: I see, it makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: My answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92362/is-it-correct-to-say-i-write-children-books-not-possessive-case) may help with the apparently improper dropping of the apostrophe. There have been other threads discussing say ["Why do we say a 'hotel room' rather than a 'hotel's room'?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159545/why-do-we-say-a-hotel-room-and-not-a-hotels-room).

Comment: Thanks Edwin, it's not always easy to know if I have to use the genetive or a compound noun....